# Make a python Tkinter login screen that verifies account details from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, authentication

I am trying to make a login screen in Python using Tkinter. I have got the basics to work, but however, I need the window, when run, to check the account details to check if they are in the csv file. The csv file should look like this:

> name1, password1
>
> name2, password2
>
> etc...

or like this, if necessary:

> username, password
>
> name1, password1
>
> name2, password2
>
> etc...

where the first line represents the row names.

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm


class LoginFrame(Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)

    self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
    self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

    self.entry_username = Entry(self)
    self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

    self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
    self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
    self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

    self.pack()

def _login_btn_clicked(self):
    # print("Clicked")
    username = self.entry_username.get()
    password = self.entry_password.get()

    # print(username, password)

    if username == "john" and password == "password":
        tm.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome John")
    else:
        tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")


root = Tk()
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

note that 'if username == "john" and password == "password":' was used because I wasn't quite sure how to use the account details from the CSV. Can you help me to do this so that the Tkinter window checks the details in the CSV file?

Comment: Python has a module specifically for reading csv files. Have you read through the documentation and tried some of the examples?

Comment: well, that's the problem... I don't know if there's an example for a login system that checks for the username and checks for the password corresponding to the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv


class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="OK", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.pack()

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        global p1
        with open('FILE', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            my_dict = {k:v for k,v in reader}
        p1 = self.entry_username.get()
        password1 = self.entry_password.get()
        if (my_dict[p1]) == (password1):
            auth1 = True
            welcome1 = ("Welcome", p1)
            tm.showinfo("Login info", welcome1)
            root.destroy()
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username")

root = Tk()
root.title("P1 Log in")
root.geometry('250x75')
lf = LoginFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This works well with txt files. I didn't have to use a CSV per se, but something that can be used as a CSV file (because CSV stands for Comma Separated Values which work just as well as a real CSV file for Python).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you use tkinter entry boxes rather than input() calls to get a name and password from a user is irrelevant to the problem of verifying the name and password with stored data.  I would delete the tkinter code from your question.  A cvs file is not an especially good choice for data storage in this case.  (It does not mark the key values as keys.)  If the data are only going to be used by a python program, a python file, say namepass.py, with a dict display would be easier.  An example:

```
{
'Alice': 'abc',
'Bob': 'xyz',
}
```

Then to check:

```
with open('namepass.py') as f:
    namepass = eval(f.read())
if namepass.get(name) == pass:
    # name is in dict and pass matches password
```

Comment: can you please explain the code? ill also try it out, but i want the login to be visual, so i want a login screen like the code in the question does. And if theres something else to include (like missed out code that is needed, please state that too).also wheres the place for the user to input the username? do I have to include that?

Comment: The code I gave assumes that you have already gotting the `name` and `pass` from the user.  For the purpose of the problem you asked about, it does not matter how you get them.